How can I solve the system reaching limit number of file watchs in an Expo program?
I'm doing an program in Expo, when I try to test the program(especificaly in web) it's been printing this error.
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/gabriel/Documentos/patrimonio/node_modules/object-inspect/test'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (node:internal/fs/watchers:247:19)
    at Object.watch (node:fs:2465:36)
    at NodeWatcher._watchdir (/home/gabriel/Documentos/patrimonio/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:89:24)
    at /home/gabriel/Documentos/patrimonio/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:26:14
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/gabriel/Documentos/patrimonio/node_modules/metro-file-map/src/watchers/common.js:81:31)
    at Walker.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at /home/gabriel/Documentos/patrimonio/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:187:23)


I've tried finding a way of solving in varius web sites, including multiple questions on stackoverflow, but none of then showed me how to stop or reduce the watch on the node__modules folder. The closest thing I've found was to make webpack ignore the folder, but I couldn't find the webpack.config.js file. For now I've incresed the maximum number of watches and it's been working.
